# Formdata append file upload is not working in codelgniter,Getting error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

All I am trying to do is upload files using ajax to my CodeIgniter based website.But i cannot get file field value in controller.I am getting message like  "Undefined index: 'file_1'"

How to solve this issue?

**Form**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" id="file_1" name="file_1" value="" class="field1" /> 
 <input type="button" onclick="up_img()" value="Upload" /> 
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function up_img()
{   
   formdata = false;
    var imgfile = document.getElementById("file_1"); 
    formdata = new FormData(); 
    formdata.append("file_1",imgfile.files[0]);
    $.ajax({  
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/save_project_upload/",  
        type: 'POST',   
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {  
                alert(data); 
        }  
    });  
}
```

**Controller:**

```
 function save_project_upload()
 {

echo $upfile_name           =       $_FILES['file_1']['name'];

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do a `print_r( $_FILES )` are you getting any content?

Also, be aware that this is not supported by IE8 and earlier.

You could also try to do:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#yourformID')[0]);
```

EDIT:

```
formData.append('file_1', $('input[id="file_1"]')[0].files[0]);
```

Might also solve your problem, by adding `[0]` to the DOM element.

Comment: Awesome! Good to hear :)